# Moving Bones While Weight Painting

Tags: weight-painting

I'm in Blender 2.8. Is there a way to move bones while weight painting? It doesn't seem to let me move them by pressing r on the bone I'm painting like in the tutorials :(

Thank you so much for your time!

Comment: As you asked this question, in 2.8, how can you switch your object to Weight Paint mode without getting out of the armature Pose mode?

Comment: In 2.8 (As far as I can tell) you can only go to weight paint mode by selecting the mesh in object mode. Currently I select my armature in object mode, and shift select  my mesh (in object mode as well), then go to weight paint mode. Doing this I'm able to hold 'ctrl' and click on different bones to see different weight paint areas. But I cannot rotate bones at the same time, like I see in the tutorials.

Comment: ooh ok thanks for the info. But what you say is weird because I can rotate bones. Can you when you don't have the object selected?

Comment: Wait, OK, now that I tested it, It looks like the bones couldn't rotate because I had rotation constrains on the bones active. It works now, thank you!